# Parameter Passing Converting Floats error

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing

I'm having an issue with passing parameters for this simple program. I am getting a "cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' argument '2' to 'void getData(std::string, float, float, float, float)'" error when trying to compile this program. Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong? I've been trying forever. Note: Please ignore deprecated stuff like system("PAUSE") and a few other things. This is simple the way my teacher has thought me to code and this is what he wants me using for this program. I am aware of getchar() and I use it for practice and final work. Plus this shouldn't affect the program as I have been using it without issues before on small programs for my C++ class.

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void getData(string,float,float,float,float);
void getCalc(int,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float);
void getPrint(float,float,float);

int main()
{
 int const acres=1000;
 string crop;
 float cpa[4];
 float yield[4];
 float per[4];
 float increase[4];
 float cost[4];
 float grossmin[4];
 float grossmax[4];
 float netmin[4];
 float netmax[4];
 float netave[4];
 getData(crop,cpa,yield,per,increase);
 getCalc(acres,cpa,yield,per,increase,cost,grossmin,grossmax,netmin,netmax,netave);
 getPrint(netmin,netmax,netave);
 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}

void getData(string fcrop,float fcpa[],float fyield[],float fper[],float fincrease[])
{
 for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
  cout<<"Enter the crop: ";
  getline(cin,fcrop);
  cout<<"Enter the cost per acre:$ ";
  cin>>fcpa[i];
  cout<<"Enter the yield: ";
  cin>>fyield[i];
  cout<<"Enter $/bishell: ";
  cin>>fper[i];
  cout<<"Enter the percentage increase: ";
  cin>>fincrease[i];
  cin.ignore(80,'\n');
 }
}

void getCalc(int acres,float fcpa[],float fyield[],float fper[],float fincrease[],float fcost[],float fgrossmin[],float fgrossmax[],float fnetmin[],float fnetmax[],float fnetave[])
{
 for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
  int acres=1000;
  fcost[i]=acres*fcpa[i];
  fgrossmin[i]=acres*fyield[i]*fper[i];
  fgrossmax[i]=fgrossmin[i]+(fgrossmin[i]*fincrease[i]/100);
  fnetmin[i]=fgrossmin[i]-fcost[i];
  fnetmax[i]=fgrossmax[i]-fcost[i];
  fnetave[i]=(fnetmin[i]+fnetmax[i])/2;
 }
}

void getPrint(float fnetmin[],float fnetmax[],float fnetave[])
{
 for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
  cout<<"The minumum profit is:$ "<<fnetmin[i]<<endl;
  cout<<"The maximum profit is:$ "<<fnetmax[i]<<endl;
  cout<<"The average profit is:$ "<<fnetave[i]<<endl;
 }
}
```

Comment: I guess you should use float &param[] in getDate, because your fcpa, fyield, ... are copied to stack which will be freed after return, and I think you want to use their value later in main().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the prototype you have written at the start of the program, this is written.

```
void getData(string,float,float,float,float) ;
```

It should be this instead identical to the one in its definition.

```
void getData(string,float[],float[],float[],float[]);
```

The function prototype should be same in its declaration and implementation.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Never occurred to me that I should specify them as arrays when prototyping.

Comment: Yes, you should. The declaration and implementation should match almost exactly.

Comment: @litebread, you'd think the compiler would complain about the mismatch but it doesn't, because C++ just considers it two different functions!

Comment: @Mark Mismatch of the parameter names?

Comment: not names, their types. You normally do not mention variable names in declaration.

Comment: @CodingMash true for declaration in prototyping it is not needed, although I have heard that it is possible to include them.